# Change URL Dynamically Without Adding Previous To History Stack

Tags: javascript

A stackoverflow question URL includes a servlet, id#, and title like so...

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page
```

My webiste works the same way with URL's like so...

```
localhost:8443/user/1/admin
```

The query I do on the backend to get the users info only requires the id number. The name of the user after that is just for show. So if you typed this into the browser for `localhost:8443/user/1/a` it would give you the exact same page as this `localhost:8443/user/1/admin`

Stackoverflow is capable of noticing that the end part of the URL is missing and add it back. So if you put this into the address bar

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify
```

They will change it to this dynamically

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page
```

Now I did reading about changing URL's dynamically on stackoverflow and everyone kept referring to  `history.pushstate` so I tried it. The problem with this is it adds the incorrect URL to the history stack. What I would like to accomplish is change the URL to the path it should be and not include the wrong URL to the history stack. So if the user decides to go back they go back to the actual page they were on last not, `stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify`. Just like stackoverflow does it. How could I do this!?

Comment: Not tested, but you may want to look into [`window.location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Methods) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [replaceState method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method).

Answer (score 1):

Try using history.replaceState instead of history.pushState